# Get application id of spawned oozie job

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

When an oozie launcher spawns another hadoop job, is there any way to get the application ID, or even better the resource manager link, to that spawned application?  It seems like the oozie launcher is only aware of its own id.

This is with a Spark action.

Comment: What is the Oozie version you are using?

Comment: *"is there any way"* -- you mean, like waiting for the Action to terminate, then retrieving the YARN app ID for that Action, then extracting the YARN logs for that App ID, then parsing the log to retrieve whatever app ID is reported by the Spark driver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below inbuilt oozie EL function to get the application Id.

```
wf:actionExternalId(String node)
```

More details on available EL functions here: http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2_Expression_Language_Functions

Comment: Unfortunately, the `externalId` field contains id of the MR job Oozie uses to poll status of the actual spark application. It doesn't contain `applicationId` of the spark action itself.